# variable value only comparing this two list

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

( I cannot edit my old question I couldont reach edit tool) ,SO I will send it again 
Finding variable value in a list. Input (uppercase letter is variable name):

```
[ 1,   [2, X],   Y,        [4, Y, X]]
[ 1,   U,        [3, U],   [4, Z, 10]]
```

example output:

```
X = 10
U = [2, 10]
Y = [3, [2, 10]]
z = [3, [2, 10]]
```

How can we find variable value only comparing this two list?
@user 
I  want to evaluate each variable: Given X = 10, U = [2, X] = [2, 10], Y = [3,U] = [3,[2,X]] = [3,[2,10], Z = Y. So each single variable in one list can be resolved with it corresponding "equation in the other list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in list finding value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387632/in-list-finding-value)

Comment: it's ok to post homework questions, but show us what you've tried! Anyway: check function "zip" and concept "unpacking Argument Lists" in python docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. iterate over both lists simultaneously.
2. for every 2 items in the same position:
   if they're both numbers make sure they're equale. if not, return false
   if one is a variable and the other is a value, add the pair to an "assignment set"
3. apply the assignment set on the two lists (replace each occurrence of the var with the value)
4. if you reached the end of the lists with no conflicts, return the assignment set.